# Only hibernate when closing the lid, display sleep otherwise?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management, hibernate

I am looking for a way to hibernate (i.e. RAM saved to HDD then turned off) **only** when closing the lid. When the lid is opened, I expect OSX to simply turn off the screen after X minutes (i.e. everything keeps running). Mostly what a Windows PC does out of the box.

`pmset` does not seem to make possible controlling what happens when closing the lid.

Comment: You mean that the mac should hibernate (write RAM to disk) and not sleep when you close the lid, right?

Comment: Was your question solved?

Comment: @n1000 no, I am in hibernate mode 25, and it behaves exactly as I want in lid-not-closed state but it does not hibernate when closing the lid... I tested playing music: closing the lid does not stop the music.

Comment: Sorry - I am confused. So it does not sleep at all when the lid is closed? Maybe you want to clarify your question...

Comment: @n1000 done. Yes, it does not hibernate when the lid is closed (the music keeps playing). But at least since I changed the hibernate mode to 25, it behaves as I wanted with the lid opened (only the screen turns off, the network keeps connected, programs keep running, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate only (not sleep) when closing the lid:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

And to go back to "normal" behavior:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3
```

As for the sleep behavior with an open lid, just slide the Computer sleep timer to `Never`in System Preferences > Energy Saver. Alternatively do

```
sudo pmset -a sleep 0
```