# How to set MacBook Pro to eventuallly fully hibernate if on battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, power, hibernate

I have a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) with macOS Monterey 12.4.

Here are my battery settings:
[image: Battery settings screenshot when charging]
When unplugged:
[image: Battery settings screenshot when unplugged]

During the week, I use it (with its lid closed) plugged in via USB-C to my Dell U4320Q display, which charges it.

On the weekend, sometimes I unplug it (and its lid remains closed).

Why does it then drain the battery?

I'd think that after some amount of time being unplugged with its lid closed (maybe after 30 mins) it would automatically switch into a full hibernation and not use any battery power at all.

I ran `pmset -g | grep hibernatemode` from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/426449/53510 and the result was `hibernatemode 3`.

```
pmset -g 
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 womp                 1
 displaysleep         10
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 disksleep            10
```

What settings should I change (and how) so that it will behave how I expected?

P.S. I've also already seen [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-sleep-and-wake-settings-mchle41a6ccd/mac) and these very old questions:

- [Do MacBooks have a true "Hibernate" option?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51725/do-macbooks-have-a-true-hibernate-option)
- [How to add hibernate mode to MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126669/how-to-add-hibernate-mode-to-macbook-pro)
- [Only hibernate when closing the lid, display sleep otherwise?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192154/only-hibernate-when-closing-the-lid-display-sleep-otherwise?rq=1)

Comment: I think battery settings may show different options when you aren't charging, can you take a screenshot of that? I have this problem too, where my unused macs drain their battery...never fully figured out why.

Comment: @JBallin I added another screenshot above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Realizing that the new OS split's up the settings for "Battery" and "Power Adapter", instead of showing different values based on charging state - so the 2nd screenshot may not be necessary.

Comment: An unvalidated assumption I have is that my airpods/magic keyboard/trackpad sometimes wake up my mac, and then it doesn't properly go back into sleep mode. Do you have any devices that may be trying to connect?

Comment: @JBallin I don't think so.

Comment: Yesterday my MBP suddenly went black while I was using it. Even following tutorials to reset the SMC and NVRAM etc, I couldn't get it to power back on, and neither could the Apple Store Genius Bar. Now they're overnighting it to their service center for repair, which costs me $678 + tax, and I'll never buy an Apple product again.